# Using Twilio Can't contact my paid subscribers "From/To pair violates a blacklist rule."

Tags: php, twilio

I was sending out Phone calls to my subscribers (who pay for this information) via Twilio with PHP with no problem, but now I am getting a fatal error

"The message From/To pair violates a blacklist rule."

Below is the error message.  Any ideas as to what I can do?

```
[19-Feb-2014 07:36:06 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Services_Twilio_RestException' with message 'The message From/To pair violates a blacklist rule.' in /Services/Twilio.php:293

Stack trace:

#0 /twilio-php-latest/Services/Twilio.php(217): Services_Twilio->_processResponse(Array)
#1 /Services/Twilio/ListResource.php(92): Services_Twilio->createData('/2010-04-01/Acc...', Array)
#2 /Services/Twilio/Rest/Messages.php(24): Services_Twilio_ListResource->_create(Array)
#3 /Services/Twilio/Rest/Messages.php(71): Services_Twilio_Rest_Messages->create(Array)
#4 /alerts_text_wakeup.php(532): Services_Twilio_Rest_Messages->sendMessage('1XXXXXXXXXX', '1XXXXXXXXXX', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
#5 {main}
thrown in /Services/Twilio.php on line 293
```

Comment: Have you read this [Can my Twilio SMS messages be blacklisted as spam](http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-my-twilio-sms-messages-be-blacklisted-as-spam)

Comment: What exactly is your code trying to do? Is this a subscriber who has decided to unsubscribe. Or did you try to delete a phone number etc?

Answer (score 6):

Twilio Evangelist here,

It sounds a lot like one of your subscribers has [sent you an SMS containing 'STOP'](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/does-twilio-support-stop-block-and-cancel-aka-sms-filtering) as detailed by [Error 21610](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21610). Check your SMS logs for SMS from the person you are trying to send to, as they may have opted out of your service. Twilio will have noticed this, and will prevent you form contacting that person again.

If you cannot find any messages like this, I would suggest you contact help@twilio.com with your Account SID and the To/From pair. They can check this out for you.

Because customers can opt out, I would generally advise people to handle this sort of error gracefully.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue and turns out we're sending same message (test message) to same mobile number (test mobile) within a short period of time. See here http://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-my-twilio-sms-messages-be-blacklisted-as-spam